# How can I "Sign in with Twitter" from within Twitter.app's UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, twitter, oauth

Whenever my app redirects to the Twitter OAuth page, the request opens in Safari.

I've replaced unique keys with "X" and changed the name of my website to example.com for privacy reasons.

When you open a link in Twitter (I tried within DMs) it first sends you to a t.co URL that then redirects to the actual URL. This redirect happens within Twitter.app and I wanted to recreate this behavior. Below you will see how t.co redirects the requests.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: private,max-age=300
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 162
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 05:01:35 UTC
expires: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 05:06:35 GMT
server: tsa_b
set-cookie: muc=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX; Expires=Sun, 25 Dec 2016 05:01:35 GMT; Domain=t.co
x-connection-hash: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
x-response-time: 11
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

<noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://example.com/"></noscript><title>http://example.com/</title><script>window.opener = null; location.replace("http:\/\/example.com\/")</script>
```

And now when I try to use this same method, the redirect does not remain in Twitter.app but rather opens the URL in Safari.app. Below you will see how I use the same method to redirect the request to no avail.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: @XXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 384
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 05:02:54 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur

<noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></noscript><title>https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</title><script>window.opener = null; location.replace("https:\/\/twitter.com\/oauth\/authorize?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");</script>
```

Before you suggest it: the Location header is not an option because the Location header will open iOS Web Apps (i.e. "Add to Homescreen") requests within Safari, therefore leaving the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Using the old https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token= endpoint will open in Safari. Change the endpoint to the new https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=. I discovered the solution by MITMing the request of a site that did it successfully.